# Add a Max value calculated column to a Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a Max value calculated column for trw1, trw2, and trw3. However I can not get the calculated column to work in the where clause.

```
select *, s.knum as SPI_Knum, s.customer_id as Customer_id, s.season as SPI_Season,
   s.inv as Inventory, s.owner_type as Room_type, s.status, s.trw1, s.trw2, s.trw21, 
   b.[ln curr bal] as MTG_Bal,
   (select max(HighTrw)
    from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate(HighTrw)
   ) as High_TRW
where m.knum is null
   and d.knum is null
   and st.customer_id is null
   and b.[ln curr bal] between '15000' and '7500'
   and max(HighTrw) between '625' and '600'
```

I am trying to use this to set criteria. so basically I need to show anything that has a value between 15000 and 7500 but also has a TRW between 625 and 600 from the calculated row.

Comment: You have no FROM clause

Comment: You have several challenges here. First of all you are using between but you are listing the higher values first. See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) to learn about how evil between can be. You have no FROM. You are trying to evaluate MAX with no grouping. The challenge for anybody helping you here is that we don't know what you are trying to do. We need lots of details. [mcve]

Comment: You also seem to be missing a GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to successfully use the `where` clause, you'll need to use the entire subquery:

```
select s.id, s.trw1, s.trw2, s.trw3, 
            (select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw3)) As updatedate(HighTrw))
            as High_TRW
from my_table as s
where (select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw3)) As updatedate(HighTrw)) between '600' and '625'
```